# Рендер иконок по условию

Tags: vue.js, api

есть такой массив который прилетает с get запроса
comfort: ["wc", "wifi", "coffee"]
0: "wc"
1: "wifi"
2: "coffee"

Есть в разметке 3 картинки - которые должны отображаться если такие ключи есть

```
<img src="@/assets/images/icons/ws-icon.svg">
<img src="@/assets/images/icons/comfort-icon.svg" alt="">
<img src="@/assets/images/icons/wifi-icon.svg" alt="">
```

Comment: `<img v-if="comfort.includes('wc')" src="//" >` и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, а еслі будет картінок 10 или 15 ...
https://jsfiddle.net/q2rzssxr/
Хороший пример, у меня правда не заработал

Comment: попробуйте сделать `return require('@/assets/' + this.pics[index] + '.png');` в функции `getPic`. Тогда картинки будут нормально резолвится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если имя ключа легко переводится в имя иконки, то можно поступить следующим образом:

1. Сохраняем массив ключей вот сюда:

   ````
   data () {
     return {
       keys: [],
       ...
     }
   }```
   ````
2. Создаём `computed`-свойство `icons`, которое возвращает массив урлов иконок на основе массива ключей, вот так:

   ````
   computed: {
     icons () {
       const res = []
       for (let i = 0; i < this.keys.length; i++) {
         res.push(`...icons/${this.keys[i]}-icon.svg`
       }
       return res
     }
   }```
   ````
3. Используем `v-for`, чтобы отрисовать иконки:

   `<img v-for="url in icons" src="url" .../>`

Тадааам! Минимум кода, максимум иконок!

Comment: покажите пожалуйста код - не понял как реализовать вашей идеей, ещё круто если это реативно всё было

Comment: "... круто если это реактивно всё было" - А что, можно по-другому?

Comment: Вот Вам код, пожалуйста. Всегда к Вашим услугам